# 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'

Tags: django

I have created a separate user profile app for an app am working following this tutorial https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/profiles so I want the profile to be updated at the same time as the password or username so I created my models in profiles/models.py and I just import it to the authentication model.

According to the tutorial, it should work but I keep on getting this error. Let me share my **authentication/serializers.py**

```
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    def validate(self, data):
        # The `validate` method is where we make sure that the current
        # instance of `LoginSerializer` has "valid". In the case of logging a
        # user in, this means validating that they've provided an email
        # and password and that this combination matches one of the users in
        # our database.
        email = data.get('email', None)
        password = data.get('password', None)

        # As mentioned above, an email is required. Raise an exception if an
        # email is not provided.
        if email is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'An email address is required to log in.'
            )

        # As mentioned above, a password is required. Raise an exception if a
        # password is not provided.
        if password is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A password is required to log in.'
            )

        # The `authenticate` method is provided by Django and handles checking
        # for a user that matches this email/password combination. Notice how
        # we pass `email` as the `username` value. Remember that, in our User
        # model, we set `USERNAME_FIELD` as `email`.
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)

        # If no user was found matching this email/password combination then
        # `authenticate` will return `None`. Raise an exception in this case.
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'A user with this email and password was not found.'
            )

        # Django provides a flag on our `User` model called `is_active`. The
        # purpose of this flag to tell us whether the user has been banned
        # or otherwise deactivated. This will almost never be the case, but
        # it is worth checking for. Raise an exception in this case.
        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'This user has been deactivated.'
            )

        # The `validate` method should return a dictionary of validated data.
        # This is the data that is passed to the `create` and `update` methods
        # that we will see later on.
        return {
            'email': user.email,
            'username': user.username,
            'token': user.token
        }


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Handles serialization and deserialization of User objects."""

    # Passwords must be at least 8 characters, but no more than 128
    # characters. These values are the default provided by Django. We could
    # change them, but that would create extra work while introducing no real
    # benefit, so let's just stick with the defaults.
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True
    )
    # When a field should be handled as a serializer, we must explicitly say
    # so. Moreover, `UserSerializer` should never expose profile information,
    # so we set `write_only=True`.
    profile = ProfileSerializer(write_only=True)
    # We want to get the `bio` and `image` fields from the related Profile
    # model.
    bio = serializers.CharField(source='profile.bio', read_only=True)
    image = serializers.CharField(source='profile.image', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'token',)
        fields = (
            'email', 'username', 'password', 'token', 'profile', 'bio',
            'image',
        )

        # The `read_only_fields` option is an alternative for explicitly
        # specifying the field with `read_only=True` like we did for password
        # above. The reason we want to use `read_only_fields` here is because
        # we don't need to specify anything else about the field. For the
        # password field, we needed to specify the `min_length` and
        # `max_length` properties too, but that isn't the case for the token
        # field.
        read_only_fields = ('token',)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """Performs an update on a User."""

        # Passwords should not be handled with `setattr`, unlike other fields.
        # This is because Django provides a function that handles hashing and
        # salting passwords, which is important for security. What that means
        # here is that we need to remove the password field from the
        # `validated_data` dictionary before iterating over it.
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)

        # Like passwords, we have to handle profiles separately. To do that,
        # we remove the profile data from the `validated_data` dictionary.
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', {})

        for (key, value) in validated_data.items():
            # For the keys remaining in `validated_data`, we will set them on
            # the current `User` instance one at a time.
            setattr(instance, key, value)

        if password is not None:
            # `.set_password()` is the method mentioned above. It handles all
            # of the security stuff that we shouldn't be concerned with.
            instance.set_password(password)

        # Finally, after everything has been updated, we must explicitly save
        # the model. It's worth pointing out that `.set_password()` does not
        # save the model.
        instance.save()

        for (key, value) in profile_data.items():
            # We're doing the same thing as above, but this time we're making
            # changes to the Profile model.
            setattr(instance.profile, key, value)

        if bio is not None:
            # `.set_password()` is the method mentioned above. It handles all
            # of the security stuff that we shouldn't be concerned with.
            instance.setattr(bio)

            # Save the profile just like we saved the user.
        instance.profile.save()

        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UserRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    renderer_classes = (UserJSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # There is nothing to validate or save here. Instead, we just want the
        # serializer to handle turning our `User` object into something that
        # can be JSONified and sent to the client.
        serializer = self.serializer_class(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # serializer_data = request.data.get('user', {})
        user_data = request.data.get('user',{})

        serializer_data = {
            'username': user_data.get('username', request.user.username),
            # 'email': user_data.get('email', request.user.email),
            'password': user_data.get('password', request.user.password),

            'profile': {
                'bio': user_data.get('bio', request.user.profile.bio),
                'image': user_data.get('image', request.user.profile.image)
            }
        }
        # Here is that serialize, validate, save pattern we talked about
        # before.
        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            request.user, data=serializer_data, partial=True
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The response I keep getting is :

```
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\environment\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 257, in put
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dell01\team_work\ah-django-Aqua\authors\apps\authentication\views.py", line 73, in update
    'bio': user_data.get('bio', request.user.profile.bio),
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
[02/Apr/2019 17:10:16] "PUT /api/user/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18787
```

I am stuck I need a solution to this problem because I have tried multiple solutions.

Extra info: when I comment out the profile bit in the views.py, the user is then updated.

Comment: Add your Profile model. Have you run the migrations?

Answer (score 1):

'User' object has no attribute 'profile'
-> Problem is the user object doesn't have profile in his model. In your models (user or profil) the one to one relationship is problably missing. To be sure you can check directly your database and the table Profil or User to see if there is a profil_id or user_id in one of these table.

The problem is not in your serializer or views, it's in your models.py

I read your tutorial. Maybe you forgot to add 'user' relationship to your profil model.

Look the model : 
[image]

Don't forgot to run the makemigrations / migrate command too ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had not done migrations properly.It works now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is:
`'profile': {
                'bio': user_data.get('bio', request.user.profile.bio),
                'image': user_data.get('image', request.user.profile.image)
            }` in your views.py. This error is telling you that the property profile doesn't exist.